# Finding equivalence between the algorithmic and trigonometrical solution

Tags: roots

For solving the complex equation $x^3$ = 1-i, approached through two ways:

(i)Trigonometric solution:

$x^3$ = $\sqrt(2)(\cos(\dfrac{-\pi}{4}) + i\sin(\dfrac{-\pi}{4}))$

In the generalized form, with $2k\pi$ as the interval for repetition 
of the roots.

$x^3$ = $\sqrt(2)(\cos(8k-1).\dfrac{\pi}{4}) + i\sin(8k-1).\dfrac{\pi}{4}))$

By De-Moivre's theorem:

$x = (2^{1/6})(\cos(8k-1)\dfrac{\pi}{12}) + i\sin(8k-1)\pi/12))$

Taking k=0, 1, 2; the 3 unique roots are:

k=0:

$x_1 = (2^{1/6})(\cos(-\pi/12)+i\sin(-\pi/12)) => (2^{1/6})(\cos 15^{\circ} - i\sin 15^{\circ})$

k=1:

$x_2 = (2^{1/6})(\cos(7\pi/12) + i\sin(7\pi/12))$ => $(2^{1/6})(\cos(105^{\circ}) + i\sin 105^{\circ})$=> $(2^{1/6})(-\sin15^{\circ} + i\cos15^{\circ})$

k=2:

$x_3 = (2^{1/6})(\cos(15\pi/12) + i\sin(15\pi/12))$
$=> (2^{1/6})(\cos(225^{\circ}) + i\sin(225^{\circ}))$
$=> (2^{1/6})(\dfrac{-1-i}{\sqrt(2)})$

===============================================================

(ii) Algebraic solution:
Have first substituted x = a+bi, found the corresponding real and 
imaginary parts' equations as :

$a^3$ - 3a$b^2$ =1   --(x)

$b^3$ - 3b$a^2$ =1   --(y)

Equating (x) and (y), got another equation:

$a^3$ - 3a$b^2$ = $b^3 - 3ba^2 $      --(z)

=> $a^3$ - 3a$b^2$ - $b^3 + 3ba^2$ = 0

Avoided the solving of cubic, and took the approach of breaking up 
the cubic equation into a product of a linear and a quadratic equation.

The form achieved is : (a-b)($a^2$+4.a.b+$b^2$) = 0    --(d)

The 3 roots are obtained as:

(i)  a=b, substituting this into (x) or (y), get the value as $a_1=b_1=
(-\dfrac{1}{2})^(\dfrac{1}{3})$ = -0.79370

(ii) solving the quadratic equation, get the roots as:

$a_2$ = (-2 + $\sqrt(3)$).b --(1)

$a_3$ = (-2 - $\sqrt(3)$).b --(2)

Substituting (1) into (x), get the value for
 $b_2=\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{(5 +3\sqrt3)}{8}}$ = 1.084;

which yields value of $a_2$
               =(-2 + $\sqrt3)(\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{(5 -3\sqrt3)}{8}})$   --(3)

```
           =>(-0.2679491924)(1.084)

           => -0.29051
```

The root pair is : (-0.29051, 1.084)

Substituting (2) into (x),

get the value for $b_3=\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{(5-3\sqrt(3))}{8}}$ = $\sqrt[3]{-0.02451}$ = -0.29051;

which yields value of $a_3$
                =(-2 -$\sqrt3$)(-0.29051)     --(4)

```
            => 1.084
```

This root is principal root: (1.084, -0.29051)

It can be checked by comparing the values of $a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2, a_3, b_3$ with trigonometrical solution; that match is there. I mean that the imaginary and real parts of the roots as given by 3 trigonometrical solutions and 3 algebraic solutions concur.
On checking with the wolframalpha site, it is seen it is the case that for all 3 roots.

<del>I want to ask an unrelated but an important question that concerns the equality of $a_2$ to $b_3$, & $b_2$ to $a_3$. Is it obvious from the quadratic equation in (d), about the equality of the parts of roots. Means is there any way to tell in advance by looking at the quadratic equation about such equality.</del>

<del>As an addendum to this problem- Is it possible to find the value of $cos (n^{\circ})$ or $sin (n^{\circ})$, where n is value of any angle, say $15^{\circ}$ by algebraic solution. It is somewhat important to get the solution as equating the principal root and the corresponding algebraic solution (one lying in 4th quadrant) don't help; as the answer is: $\cos15^{\circ}$ = $\frac{\sqrt6 + \sqrt2}{4}$.</del>

Comment: $\cos (15^{\circ}) = \dfrac{ \sqrt 3 +1 }{2 \sqrt 2}$ and $\sin (15^{\circ}) = \dfrac{ \sqrt 3 -1 }{2 \sqrt 2}$ and you can derive these from $\cos (30^{\circ})=\frac{\sqrt 3}2$  and $\sin (30^{\circ})=\frac12$ but other angles are not so simple

Comment: @Henry: I mean computing by the given equation $x^3$ = 1-i, and its algebraic solution only; for the case x = cos$15^{\circ}$, or sin$15^{\circ}$.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: It is for computing $ \cos (15^{\circ})$ or $\sin (15^{\circ})$ using the algebraic approach of solution to the equation : $x^3$ = 1- i.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The angle halving formulas say

$$\cos \frac a2=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos a}2},\\
\sin\frac a2=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos a}2}.
$$
These give you access to the expressions of the sine and cosine of $15°$.

Comment: Is there a connection to the algebraic solution of the equation $x^3$ = 1 - i? If yes, please give some more hint. I am asking this as specifically in context of the equation concerned & its algebraic solution.

Comment: @jiten: hem, read your last sentence in the OP.

Comment: Cannot gather anything by what 'last sentence' is being referred to. Please be more explicit about what is meant by OP.

Comment: @jiten Original Post or Original Poster, depending on context.